# How to check table tr th/td exist in the page, php

Tags: php

I am trying to verify `table` `tr` `th`/`td` or `dl` `dt`/`dd` exist or not in the page. So I tried to do something like below.

```
foreach($links as $k => $val){
    $html = file_get_contents($val);
     if (strpos($val, "</table>") !== false) {
       echo "table exist";
     }
     elseif(strpos($val, "</dl>")!== false){
            echo "dl exist";
     }
}
```

But it's not working. Any possible way to verify html has certain elements? Or is html has certain amount elements. for example more than 5 `th` or more than 5 `dd`

Comment: Try PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser :http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` of DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('filename.html');
$tableRow = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach ($tableRow as $tr) {
   echo $tr->nodeValue;
   echo $tableRow->length;
}
```